# File reverse engineering - .tbl format

Tags: file-format, encryption

I've been trying to google any information about how can i create a viewer for some custom file formats.

In my case I've extracted multiple `.tbl` files from game sources. This file contains a database table. From what I was able to google, I was able to extract file header. I have tried some tbl-viewers but they say file is corrupted, so i assume that custom encryption presents here.

First Bytes of file 1:

```
00000000    46 54 41 42 4c 45 00 00 00 00 10 00 21 00 00 00
00000010    03 00 00 00 2c 00 00 00 b0 00 00 00 b4 00 00 00
00000020    10 00 00 00 c4 02 00 00 00 00 00 00 01 00 00 00
00000030    02 00 00 00 03 00 00 00 04 00 00 00 05 00 00 00
```

First Bytes of file 2:

```
00000000    46 54 41 42 4c 45 00 00 00 00 10 00 22 00 00 00
00000010    15 00 00 00 2c 00 00 00 b4 00 00 00 ca 00 00 00
00000020    58 00 00 00 7a 0c 00 00 00 00 00 00 01 00 00 00
00000030    02 00 00 00 03 00 00 00 04 00 00 00 06 00 00 00
```

So in this case first 12 bytes seem to be the file header

```
46 54 41 42 4c 45 00 00 00 00 10 00
```

which stand for `FTABLE......`

And this is where i am stuck at. I didnt find information on what to do next to achieve my goal

Comment: Have you tried reverse engineering the game software that consumes these .tbl files to determine how the files are parsed by the game?

Comment: ".tbl" for *table* is a very generic file extension. That may be the reason why "common .tbl viewers" cannot read them. As this is a game, it's most likely the file contains data in a format especially written for that one game, and so it's the only software that can read it. It is probably not *encrypted*  So, basically, what @Jason says.

Answer (score 1):

This format looks like little endian 32bit ints starting at Byte 12.

The data shows low entropy so it's unlikely to be encrypted, as well as having consistent 0 valued MSB's in consistent positions across both messages.